# Не отображаются спрайты в 2d игре

Tags: unity3d, 2d, спрайт, unity3d-ui

Вот моя проблема: 
когда приближаю камеру, то видно только текст, кнопки и панели.

Т.е. только UI-элементы.

Все спрайты видно, только если сильно отдалить камеру.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Два раза тыкнуть на спрайт в иерархии не решает проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связана с логикой обзора. Unity просто фокусируется на UI слое. Дважды нажмите на любой из нужных вам объектов и фокус поменяется на их слой. Так же можно переключаться и обратно

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо выбрать нужный `Sprite` в `Inspector` и пару раз нажать кнопку `F`.